# What is the Weyl group of this group?

Tags: finite-groups, lie-groups, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be the group  $GL_{n_1}(q^{l_1})\times GL_{n_2}(q^{l_2})\times GL_{n_3}(q^{l_3})$. Here $GL_{n_1}(q^{l_1})$ is the rational points of $GL(n,\bar {\mathbf{F}}_q)$. My question  iis what is the Weyl group $W$ of $G$, and is there a reference to compute it. I believe that it is not just $S=\operatorname{Sym}_{n_1}\times \operatorname{Sym}_{n_2}\times\operatorname{Sym}_{n_3}$, there is some extra factors in $W$ other than $S$.

Comment: Rational points over what field?

Comment: over $F_{q^l_i}$ for each i. Actually I consider $G$ as fixed points of a standard Frobenius map on te centralizer of a semisimple element in the algebraic group $GL(n,\bar{F_p})$